# How to get LonLat Points between a LineString or 2 LonLat Points

Tags: openlayers-2

i have a marker and i want to move him on a LineString. So i know start LonLat and end LonLat and also the time between.

I tried to calculate it my self with "getLayerPxFromLonLat" and then count x+1 y+1 and after that i switch them back with "getLonLatFromPixel". So i can calculate it my self (e.g. 10 Seconds = 5 Points between start and end) but when i the map moves the function got wrong data.

I hope u have a idea for that Problem or an Idea how to get Points on a LineString.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer was realy easy.

convert all Lonlat Data to SphericalMercator.

from SphericalMercator1 to SphericalMercator2 use the diff from x/y and divide by the steps you want.
after that it is SphericalMercator1.lan +/- (diff/steps)

thats it!